# Gulp connect-livereload not working on simple app in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

I'm trying to get connect-livereload to work in order to dynamically insert the script needed for livereload. ([NPM connect-reload](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-livereload))

My gulpfile relevant snippet:

```
var express_app = require('./app.js')(),
    express = require('express'),
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    lr = require('tiny-lr')();

gulp.task('default', function() {
    initServer();
    initLiveReload();
}

// This is supposed to insert the middleware
function initServer() {
    express_app.use(require('connect-livereload')());
    express_app.use(express.static(__dirname));
    express_app.listen(3000);
}

function initLiveReload() {
    lr.listen(35729);
};
```

My app.js relevant snippet:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

module.exports = function() {
    return app;
};
```

So I'm guessing maybe I'm not exporting the app object properly? The thing is, the server actually works from the gulpfile and I get no errors at all. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the HTML source to see if the LR script tag is present? Does LiveReload work when you use the [browser extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei) instead?